# How to set NLS_DATE_FORMAT | ZF2 with oci8 | Oracle 12

Tags: sql, oracle, zend-framework2, date-formatting

I'm working with ZendFramework2 and my DB is Oracle 12.

I would like to set the date format for all my date fields.

For now, when i select a date field the result is dd/mm/aa, i would like dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss.

( i'm using TableGateway object the same way Zf2's Skeleton Application )

Can i do that in my config file ?

( The sql code to do that whould be "alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'; "
)

Thanks for help.

```
<code>
------
config\autoload\db.config.global.php
------
<?php
return array(
  'db' => array(
    'driver' => 'OCI8',
    'connection_string' => " (DESCRIPTION =
                                (SDU = 8888)
                                (ADDRESS_LIST =
                                  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = tcp)(HOST = 127.0.0.1)(PORT = 9999))
                                )
                                (CONNECT_DATA =
                                  (SERVER = DEDICATED)
                                  (SERVICE_NAME = MYDB)
                                )
                              )",
    'character_set' => 'AL32UTF8',
  ),
   'service_manager' => array(
           'factories' => array(
               'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter'
                       => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory'
           )
     )
);
</code>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, but I was using Doctrine 2 instead Zend\Db. I was using of course Oracle. Doctrine 2 solves this changing the session after connection:

```
class OracleSessionInit 
{

    protected $_defaultSessionVars = array(
        'NLS_TIME_FORMAT' => "HH24:MI:SS",
        'NLS_DATE_FORMAT' => "YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS",
        'NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT' => "YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS",
        'NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT' => "YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZH:TZM",
        'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS' => ".,",
    );

    /**
     * @param \Doctrine\DBAL\Event\ConnectionEventArgs $args
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function postConnect(ConnectionEventArgs $args)
    {
        if (count($this->_defaultSessionVars)) {
            array_change_key_case($this->_defaultSessionVars, \CASE_UPPER);
            $vars = array();
            foreach ($this->_defaultSessionVars as $option => $value) {
                $vars[] = $option." = '".$value."'";
            }
            $sql = "ALTER SESSION SET ".implode(" ", $vars);
            $args->getConnection()->executeUpdate($sql);
        }
    }
}
```

The entire file [OracleSessionInit](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Event/Listeners/OracleSessionInit.php).

You could consider Doctrine 2 to solve this. But if you can't or you don't want maybe you can check this out [Zend Whitepaper PHP and Oracle](https://www.zend.com/topics/oracle_and_php.pdf) page 3-4, "Connecting the DB" section. It's a ZF1 solution and I didn't try. But it's easy to understand the idea and adapt to ZF2.

Answer (score 0):

> when i select a date field the result is dd/mm/aa, i would like dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss.

The **format** that you see for a **DATE** is only for **display**. DATE is stored in an internal format of `7 bytes` which is Oracle's proprietary format.

You could use **TO_CHAR** at individual SQL level to convert the date into a string to display in your desired format.

For example,

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(date_column, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') my_format FROM table_name;
```

Also, remember that the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` has an **order of precedence**.

Let's see the **chronological order of precedence**, i.e. starting from highest to least:

- Using **TO_CHAR** or **TO_DATE** at the **individual sql statement**
- `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT=’whatever format model you want’;`
- Setting it as an **OS environment variable** on the **client machine**
- Setting of `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is in the **database initialization parameters**

---

**UPDATE** OP can't handle the **date-formatting** at SQL level.

In that case, it is just a **display format** to be taken care by the **client/OS** and nothing to do at database/query level. Whichever client/OS you are using to display the **DATE**, make sure you modify the date format of the client/OS to display it in your **desired format**.

Comment: i can't do SQL, because sql orders are generated by a ZF2 TableGateway object. So i can't specify individual to_char format. But i'm thinking....may i parameter my TableGateway object to format date fields ?

Comment: @EdouardMonnier Then as I said, you could just change the client NLS settings. The issue is outside of database in that case. For example, in your Windows laptop, if you specify the date format at OS level, then all the date values would be displayed in that format